# how to display thumbnails in listview like explorer does?

Tags: c++, listview, explorer, thumbnails, syslistview32

could you please point c++ code example to display videos and images thumbnails in listview?

Comment: i need example of IExtractImage & IShellImageStore use

Comment: intresting link: http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3806.asp?SK=

Answer (score 3):

I can help with images, but not videos:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/GdiPThumbnailsViewer.aspx

Basically you use a normal list control and add the images to an associated image list.  There are some gotchas though - looks like you have to use the CImageView::ReplaceImage instead of CImageView::AddImage, else the images don't appear correctly.  Masking the image may also require some work.

Comment: very usefull link - thank you! - i have no points to vote for your answer - but the link is a greate example - i google a lot of time but can't find it!